# Написал функцию, которая удаляет повторы в массиве. Но массив двумерный, и она удаляет повторы там, где не надо

Tags: php, массивы

Я накидал функцию (код ее ниже), которая удаляет у массива повторяющиеся значения, если они идут друг за другом, оставляя при этом только первое значение.

Есть массив до обработки:

```
Array
(
    [Понедельник, 10 Декабря] => Array
        (
            [13:00] => "Принцесса де Монпасье" Мелодрама 16+
            [15:20] => "Боец" Драма 16+
            [17:20] => "Роден" Драма 18+
            [19:20] => "Шесть жен Генри Лефэя" Драма 16+
            [21:00] => "Принцесса де Монпасье" Мелодрама 16+
            [23:20] => "Боец" Драма 16+
            [01:20] => "Роден" Драма 18+
        )

    [Вторник, 11 Декабря] => Array
        (
            [09:20] => "Роден" Драма 18+
            [11:20] => "Шесть жен Генри Лефэя" Драма 16+
            [13:00] => "Безумные деньги" Комедия 16+
            [14:40] => "Мистер Штайн идет в онлайн" Комедия 16+
            [16:25] => "Железный занавес" Драма 12+
```

Обратите внимание на строки `[01:20] => "Роден"` Драма 18+ и `[09:20] => "Роден" Драма 18+`. Они в разных днях, но как бы идут друг за другом. Если применить мою функцию, то `[09:20] => "Роден" Драма 18+` удалится, и Вторник начнется с `[11:20] => "Шесть жен Генри Лефэя" Драма 16+`, а это нехорошо. Как предотвратить удаление значения, если оно есть в конце одного дня и в начале следующего? То есть, мне нужно, чтобы функция работала в пределах одного дня, но для каждого дня недели...

```
function deleteReps($week){
    if( /* $_POST['deleteReps'] &&  */$week ){
        foreach($week as $date => $day){
            foreach($day as $time => $show){
                if($show == $rep){
                    unset($week[$date][$time]);
                }
                $rep = $show;
            }
        }
    }
    return $week;
}
```

Тут бы как-нибудь сравнить `$date` для `$show` и `$date` для `$rep`, но как выдернуть `$date`, если `$show` и `$rep` так глубоко в двумерном массиве? Спасибо!

Comment: `array_map("array_unique", $data)` не подойдет вам?

Comment: Перед внутренним foreach чистите предыдущее значение в $rep.

Comment: ан нет, не пойдет.  вам не в течение дня в целом повторы нужны, а передачи друг за другом.

Comment: еще можете `&$day` сделать, дабы не таскать с собой `$date`

Comment: @Akina, да, сработало! Спасибо!